# Can correlated random effects "steal" the variability (and the significance) from the regression coefficient?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, random-effects-model

I have time-series count data $N_{i,j}$ (population sizes in site $i$ and year $j$) and I want to correlate year-to-year changes with the environmental conditions $x_{i,j}$. For this, I am fitting this model:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\mbox{log} ( \mu_{i,j+1} ) &=& \mbox{log} ( \mu_{i,j} ) + \alpha + \beta  x_{i,j} + \gamma_j + \epsilon_{i,j}  \\
\\
N_{i,j} &\sim& \mbox{Poiss} ( \mu_{i,j} ) \\
\gamma_{j} &\sim& \mbox{Norm} (0, \sigma ) \\
\epsilon_{i,j} &\sim& \mbox{Norm} (0, \theta )
\end{eqnarray}
$$

So I'm interested in parameter $\beta$, the slope of the relationship. $\gamma_{j}$ is the random effect for year (as the residuals within single year were correlated) and $\epsilon_{i,j}$ is an overdispersion term.

**The problem is in the year specific random effect $\gamma_{j}$.** I think I have to use it, because the residuals are significantly explained by year. But, also the environmental conditions $x_{i,j}$ (climate conditions) are very much correlated within years! I.e. the climate in the same year is much more similar than accross years (as you would expect).

So the question is whether the introduced year-specific random effect $\gamma_{j}$ cannot "eat out" the variability that would be explained by the yearly variation of the climate (i.e. the term $\beta  x_{i,j}$)? In case this problem occurs, the yearly variation of the climate would go to $\gamma_{j}$ instead of $\beta  x_{i,j}$ and we could easily miss the significant relationship - i.e. the significant $\beta$ slope! Couldn't this happen? If yes, how to fit this model in such a way that the variability remains in $\beta x_{i,j}$ while at the same time the yearly autocorrelation in residuals is handled?

Answer (score 3):

Since $\gamma_j$ is assumed to follow a zero-mean normal distribution, any deviation of the predicted value of $\gamma_j$ from zero will be penalized in the likelihood function relative to the variance $\sigma^2$. Thus it will be "cheaper" in terms of likelihood to put year-consistent variability into the fixed effect $\beta$.

The reason that it is cheaper to put the variability in a fixed effect rather than a random one is that the fixed effects will be estimated to minimize the residual, and there will not be a penalization if they are too big or too small. In contrast random effects are supposed to vary following a probability distribution (in your case a normal) around zero, and thus if you need an extreme value of the random effect to explain a given observation, the observation will become very unlikely given the model, which will give a lower likelihood value. If you can explain consistent variability in terms of fixed effects rather than random effects, you will increase the likelihood values. Thus, if you use maximum likelihood estimation, you will choose parameters that do that.

For example, consider the simple model

$$y_i=\alpha + x_i + \varepsilon_i,\qquad i = 1,\dots,n$$

where $(x_i)_i=\boldsymbol{x}\sim\mathcal{N}(0, S)$ and $(\varepsilon_i)_i\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2\mathbb{I}_n)$. Let $\boldsymbol{y}=(y_i)_i$ and $\boldsymbol{\alpha}=(\alpha)_i$, $i=1,\dots, n$. The log-likelihood function is
$$
\ell_{\boldsymbol y}(\alpha, \sigma^2, S) = -\frac{1}{2}\log\mathrm{det}(S+\sigma^2\mathbb{I})- \frac{1}{2}(\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol\alpha)^\top(S+\sigma^2\mathbb{I})^{-1}(\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol\alpha)
$$
If we consider the part that depends on $\alpha$, namely the quadratic term, we can use some linear algebra to rewrite it
$$
-(\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol\alpha)^\top(S+\sigma^2\mathbb{I})^{-1}(\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol\alpha) = -\frac{1}{\sigma^2}(\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol\alpha)^\top(\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol\alpha- S(S+\sigma^2\mathbb{I})^{-1}(\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol\alpha)).
$$
The term $S(S+\sigma^2\mathbb{I})^{-1}(\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol\alpha)$ is the conditional expectation of $\boldsymbol{x}$ given the observation $\boldsymbol{y}$ which we usually denote $\mathrm{E}[\boldsymbol{x}|\boldsymbol{y}]$. This conditional expectation is in fact the [best linear unbiased predictor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_linear_unbiased_prediction) of $\boldsymbol{x}$. With this in mind we can finally rewrite the square as
$$
-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}(\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol\alpha - \mathrm{E}[\boldsymbol{x}|\boldsymbol{y}])^\top(\boldsymbol{y} - \boldsymbol\alpha- \mathrm{E}[\boldsymbol{x}|\boldsymbol{y}])-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathrm{E}[\boldsymbol{x}|\boldsymbol{y}]^\top S^{-1}\mathrm{E}[\boldsymbol{x}|\boldsymbol{y}].
$$
From this expression we see that in the first square of residuals, $\alpha$ and the predicted value of $\boldsymbol{x}$ plays a similar role, but the second penalizes deviation of the predicted value from zero. Thus maximum-likelihood estimation will always seek to describe as much variation as possible through the fixed effect $\alpha$. This holds in general.

Comment: Lars, thank you for your answer! I have a few questions: 1) why is it "cheaper to put the variability in $\beta$?" 2) Regarding the size of $\sigma^2$ vs $\beta_ix_{i,j}$, how do I compare it properly? Unfortunatelly there is a convergence problem and I have only one model run where estimate of $\sigma$ converged. The estimate is $\sigma = 0.17$, $\beta = -0.47$, $sd(x_{i,j}) = 0.06$ (should I compute `sd` of $x$? `mean` is zero), so this gives me $sd(\beta_ix_{i,j}) = 0.03$ which is much less than the $\sigma$! Does it mean that the variability is then consumed by the random effect?

Comment: Note to point 2) above - I am not comparing "variance of $\sigma^2$"  as you suggested but instead I am comparing $sd(\beta_ix_{i,j}) = 0.03$ with $\sigma$. I hope this is what you meant?

Comment: I have replaced $\gamma_i$ with $\gamma_j$ in your answer - I guess this is what you meant.

Comment: @Curious: I have updated the answer. You should compare $\sigma$ to the actual values of $\beta_i x_{i,j}$ and not their variability. If a typical value of $\beta_i x_{i,j}$ is 0.00001 and the estimated standard deviation of your random effect is 0.17, it seems that $\beta$ does not explain a lot of variation.

Comment: Lars, but the values of $x_{i,j}$ have approx normal distribution with the mean = zero, so what is the "actual value of $\beta_i x_{i,j}$" then? Mean of this term is actually zero.

Comment: I don't understand your model and the notation. Are you sure the indices are ok? If $i$ is the observation, where is the index for the group the random effect applies to? $\epsilon_i$ is the residual then, not the random effect, but what is the $x_i$? Why does it have the same index as $\epsilon_i$? What does the $(y_i)_i$ notation mean? Please make sure the indices are precise because otherwise I have troubles understanding it.

Comment: @Curious:$x_{i,j}$ is your environmental conditions? Don't you know them?

Comment: Lars, exactly, $x_{i,j}$ are *known* environmental conditions, this is the independent predictor variable

Comment: The model I write is just the simplest example I could come up with. There are $n$ noisy observations. They contain iid noise in the form of $\varepsilon_i$ and noise $x_i$ that is correlated between the different observations (which is the most basic non-trivial example of a random effect). When I write $(y_i)_i$ I mean the $n$-vector consisting of all observations. When I write the distributions of the vectors, I write the covariance matrices $S$ and $\sigma^2 \mathbb{I}_n$ that describe the correlation between the variables.

Comment: @Curious: Then there should be no problem computing $\hat\beta x_{i,j}$ where $\hat\beta$ is your estimate for $\beta$. You can compute all the values, and judge whether a 0.17 standard deviation seems to be a big deal around the values. Since you say $x_{i,j}$ have approximately zero mean, the 0.03 standard deviation does seem to imply that the contribution of $\beta$ in your model is small, but it may still be significant.

Comment: Dear Lars, sorry for period of silence. I will award the bounty to you, though your answer is not clear to me yet. Could you please rewrite indices so that at least $x_i$ and $\epsilon_i$ doesn't use the same index $i$ when in fact they are indexed differently? I am still not able to get it even after your comment. You can use the same indices as I used in my answer.

Comment: @Curious. The model I write is a generic model, not related at all to your model. It is just a very simple example. Every $y_i$ in the model is an observation of $\alpha$ plus noise $x_i+\varepsilon_i$ and both terms are unknown. The reason I split the noise term in two is that you often have independent measurement noise $\varepsilon_i$ that is caused by errors in the measurement process, and some systematic noise caused by the system you are observing. The point is that these types of systematic noise  (corresponding to $\gamma_j$ in your model) will have a specific effect on the likelihood.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your description correctly, I would say you are more likely to see a significant coefficient $\hat{\beta}$ by including a random effect. The reason is that with the introduction of $\gamma$, you now explicitly distinguish between-year variability and within-year variability. The overall variance in your data $V$ now has 2 parts

1. The variability from $\gamma$: $V_\gamma$
2. The variability from $\epsilon$: $V_\epsilon$

Without a random effect, $V_\gamma =0$ and all variability is attributed to $V_\epsilon$. The variance of the fixed effect estimator $\hat{\beta}$ is actually proportional to $V_\epsilon$. If you introduce random effects, $V_\epsilon$ will be smaller meaning $\hat{\beta}$ will have a short confidence interval (recall the confidence interval is inverse proportional to the square root of variance), thus a smaller pvalue.

Having said that, I am not sure why you want to include a random effect at the first place. My understanding is that the purpose of using random effect is to introduce correlation structure in your covariance matrix. In your case, $\gamma_j$ will make sure observations within a year are positively correlated. However, this is already achieved by using a time series model. If you extend the expression of $\log(\mu_{i,j})$ in term of $\epsilon_{i,1... j}$ (assuming no random effect) and calculate covariance between $\log(\mu_{i,j})$ and $\log(\mu_{i,k})$ for any $j \ne k$, you will find they are always positively correlated. That is the purpose of time series models. Random effect models are essentially doing the same thing, except for using some different techniques and being designed for a particular type of data (a few time points but multiple sequences).

Peter

Comment: Peter, thank you for the answer! I have to go so I will have to look at your answer in more detail later. Now just a small comment - $\epsilon$ is not the only residual variability. $\epsilon$ is only the overdispersion - main residual variability is present within the $N_{i,j} \sim \mbox{Poiss} (\mu_{i,j})$ term.

Comment: And you say $V$ is the "overall variance", don't you mean "overall residual variance" instead?

Comment: Peter, 1) I am using random effects because the residuals of the model where correlated within years. This means there is some part of between-year population growth present over all sites which is not explained by $x_{i,j}$. This is not handled by the time series model. You speak of autocorrelation on the population size, while I speak of the autocorrelation of population growth, this is a different thing. 2) Sometimes it can happen that adding random effect will in fact enlarge the confidence intervals.

Comment: I agree with comment 1). In fact, I should read your index notation more carefully. Regarding your comment 2), when you fit your model, is $\sigma$ significantly larger than zero? Sometimes adding a random/fixed effect not strongly associated with outcome will add more noise rather than explaining variability in outcome.

Comment: *"is $\sigma$ significantly larger than zero?"* Peter, well, I think $\sigma$ is always significantly larger than zero because it simply can't be negative...

Comment: In mixed models, you can test for presence of random effect. This translates to H0: $\sigma = 0$ vs HA: $\sigma > 0$. Failing to reject H0 means there is no evidence for the specific random effect and adding it to your model will generate extra noise. See this class note for a more technical explanation http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~ane/st572/notes/lec21.pdf